# Disable div class for <a> to style the <a>

Tags: html, css, href

I have this code that styles the `<a href="#">`:

```
<div class="styled">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <div class="notStyled">
        <a href="#">another link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first link have one style and the second link have the same style, I want it to be default like a clean link.

Comment: Can you show your CSS. Maybe try `.styled > a`. That should only style the first `a`.

Comment: Or perhaps it'd be more reliable as `<a class="styled">` and apply styles to that class...

Comment: putvande is right, but as an additional note you might not want to use the default settings for the second link though, this makes links look very ugly in almost any design.

Comment: @putvande that will style children though not descendants.  Just to clarify, if there was another <a> following the inner div, that would get styled too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/q85Dc/1/),

```
.styled > a {
  color:black;
}
```

The `>` used in this means it only selects direct children of `.styled` and not ALL children.

What you are probably doing is `.styled a`, which selects all children (even nested within others), **and you don't want to do that...**

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can only guess what you have done.
From your question I get you want to style the first, but not the second `a` tag.
You could use this to style only the first `a` tag:

```
.styled > a {
    /* your styling */
}
```

The `>` selects the direct children of `.styled` so this will not style your `.notStyled a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.styled > a {
    color:red; /*custom style for the first link*/
}
```

live exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/72bQM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you did, but it looks like the second `<div>` is there just as a try to let the second link have no-style.

I suggest, instead, to give have this code

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="styled">
  <a href="#">
</div>
```

And then in CSS just

```
.styled{
/* Give the style you want */
}
```

This way you just have to add the `class="styled"` to the link you want to be styled, without using many DIVs.